# Negative binomial regression with two fixed effects variables

Tags: r, regression, fixed-effects-model, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm using the `fixest` package to fit a negative binomial regression model with two fixed effect variables. The relevant line of code is

```
m1 <- fenegbin(Total_Interactions ~ 
        Followers + anger + anticipation + disgust + fear + joy + 
            sadness + surprise + trust | 
        Page_Name + Dominant_Topic,
        data = dat)
```

My data set has around 200k rows. `Page_Name` and `Dominant_Topic` are the only two character variables whose fixed effects I'm controlling for. From what I understand, `fixest` automatically clusters standard errors based on the fixed effect variables as well. `Total_Interactions` and `Followers` are (positive) integer variables while all others are regular (positive) numeric variables.

The problem is that this line of code doesn't "stop running". This is surprising given `fixest` is supposedly the fastest fixed effects estimator package in R. After 20 minutes (on a very powerful desktop computer running Windows 11), when I kill the code, it gives me this warning:

```
NOTES: 276 observations removed because of NA values (RHS: 276).
       458/0 fixed-effects (2,237 observations) removed because 
of only 0 outcomes.
Warning: fenegbin: [Getting the fixed-effects] iteration limit 
reached (10000). (Once.)
```

I then tried using the `Dominant Topic` variable as a covariate in the above model, while recognizing that that would not produce the clustered errors I want it to, and the code worked within seconds.

```
m2 <- fenegbin(Total_Interactions ~ 
           Dominant_Topic + Followers + anger + anticipation + 
           disgust + fear + joy + sadness + surprise + 
           (trust | Page_Name) , data = dat)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are page names unique for each record and thus, multi-colinear with dominant topic?

Comment: Each record has a single page name and a single dominant topic, but there are multiple records per page name, and per dominant topic. There's no reason for the page name to be correlated with the dominant topic.